# Unable to add a row in DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to add a new row in a DataTable with values taken from a GridView row. Below is the code that am using:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Save")
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentStuDt"];
        DataRow dr = null;
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ID"] = Convert.ToInt32(gv.FooterRow.FindControl("txtInId"));
        dr["Name"] = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIName");
        dr["Class"] = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIClass");
        dr["Section"] = gv.FooterRow.FindControl("txtISec");
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        ViewState["CurrentStuDt"] = dt;

        gv.DataSource = dt;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
}
```

But am getting the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

on line

```
dr["ID"] = Convert.ToInt32(gv.FooterRow.FindControl("txtInId"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gv.FooterRow.FindControl("txtInId")
```

will give you the control not the value in it. try something like

```
TextBox myText = (TextBox)gv.FooterRow.FindControl("txtInId");
dr["ID"] = Convert.ToInt32(myText.Text);
```

Comment: I am getting an error of 'TextBox' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' and 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' as I am using the 'System.Windows.Forms' namespace

Comment: try adding the namespace with the control like System.Windows.Forms.TextBox myText = (System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)gv.FooterRow.FindControl("txtInId");

Answer (score 0):

`gv.FooterRow.FindControl("txtInId")` returns reference to control.

And the receiving control value code should looks like that:

```
string idText= (gv.FooterRow.FindControl("txtInId") as TextBox).Text;
dr["ID"] = Convert.ToInt32(idText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument);

dr["ID"] = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)gv.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtInId")).Text.ToString());
```